# How to use migration queries in MySQL tables for replace records?

Tags: mysql, replace, migration

I have some existing mysql tables.

Table 1 - lead_records

```
    leadid  leadnumber 
     1      98264*****
     2      88952*****
     3      99625*****
```

and so on.

Table 2 - counsellors

```
    cid  counselorid   leadnumber
    1     101           98264*****
    2     102           88952*****
    3     101           99625*****
```

and so on.

Now I want to change some record structure. In place of leadnumber I want to use leadid something like -

```
    cid  counselorid    leadid
    1     101           1
    2     102           2
    3     101           3
```

There are thousands of records already stored in that table? How can I replace leadnumber to lead id.

Comment: Add a new column in the table `counsellors` as  `leadid` and then update that column by leadid from `lead_records` by matching `leadnumber`

Comment: thanx , i am not much aware to mysql  so please can u write query here..

Comment: Here is the query for the update `update counsellors cs join lead_records lr on lr.leadnumber = cs.leadnumber set cs.leadid = lr.leadid` I will let you add a new column in to the table and that you should be able to do by yourself as this is very basic operation you must know.

Comment: Thankyou so much bro...It works

Answer (score 0):

Add counsellors column with index:

```
ALTER TABLE `counsellors` ADD `leadid` INT NOT NULL, ADD INDEX (`leadid`);
```

Set leadid based on leadnumber:

```
UPDATE counsellors c SET c.leadid = (SELECT l.leadid FROM lead_records l WHERE l.leadnumber = c.leadnumber LIMIT 1);
```

(optional) If everything is ok, drop column:

```
ALTER TABLE `counsellors` DROP `leadnumber`;
```